# DevContainer: hostname: No address associated with hostname

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using DevContainers on Windows 10 and WSL2 with the [desktop-lite feature](https://github.com/devcontainers/features/tree/main/src/desktop-lite), which allows me to open a browser connection to the NoVNC server at this URL:
http://localhost:6080/vnc.html?password=vscode&autoconnect=true&resize=remote

The above has been working well with containers based on Ubuntu 20.04.

I recently started using Ubuntu 22.04 containers but could not connect to the desktop. I found errors in `/tmp/Xtigervnc.log` like this:

```
hostname: No address associated with hostname
tigervncserver: Could not acquire fully qualified host name of this machine.
```

Indeed, the `/etc/hosts` file lacks an entry for the host itself:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I can fix the problem by appending an entry for the host:

```bash
sudo bash
echo "127.0.0.1 $(cat /etc/hostname)" >> /etc/hosts
```

I did not have to do any of this with containers based on Ubuntu 20.04.

Has anyone encountered similar behavior with Ubuntu 22.04?

If the problem is systematic, I wonder if it would make sense to develop a small DevContainer feature to append the entry to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comments?